# Two jQuery animations on one element in a game loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, game-loop

I am trying to let a html element jump by clicking on a button while another animation is running on that element. The animations are triggered in a game loop if conditions are met (flashing if health is critical), or if a button is clicked (jumping if fed).
Problem: every time the loop repeats, the animation function is called again and is put into the queue; flashing wouldn't stop when health is okay again. Clearing the queue in a callback function of the animation only works if it's the default queue ("fx"), but I need several custom queues.
Working with global boolean variables to allow or refuse the animation function to get called are no solution for me because I want the jump() and flash() animations to be used by several html elements.

I read about queuing and starting a 2nd queue on an element in [learn.jquery.com](https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/) and also read the [jQuery API documentations](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) about animation and queing but could not find a solution yet.

Check out flashAnimation1(), it's the expected result: queue cleared in callback so the element will stop flashing if triggering stops. But this works on the default (fx) queue only.

letJump1 (no queue) and letJump2 (custom queue) let the element rise or shrink without control.

flashAnimation2() is a flickering mess.

Can you help me please?

```js
let requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || windows.msRequestAnimationFrame;
let cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame;

let reqAnimF;

let progress = 0;
let lastRender = 0;
let animationOn = false;

const button = document.getElementById("button");
const state = document.getElementById("state");
const jump = document.getElementById("jump");
const block = $("#fadeInAndOut");

const changeStatus = () => animationOn = !animationOn;

const flashAnimation1 = (element) => { $(function() {
    element.animate( {opacity: 0}, "fast", "linear" )
    .animate( {opacity: 1}, "fast", "linear", ()=> element.clearQueue() );
    })
}

const flashAnimation2 = (element) => { $(function() {
    element.queue("flash", (next)=> {
    element.animate( {opacity: 0}, {
        duration: "fast",
        easing: "linear",
        queue: "flash"
    }).animate( {opacity: 1}, {
            duration: "fast",
            easing: "linear",
            queue: "flash",
            complete: element.clearQueue()
    });
    next();
    }).dequeue("flash");
    });
};

// Jumping: no queue
const letJump1 = (element) => { $(function() {
    element.animate( {width: "+=50", height: "+=20"}, {
        duration: "fast",
        queue: false,
        always: () => {
            element.animate( {width: "-=50", height: "-=20"}, {
                duration: "fast",
                queue: false                        
            });
        }
        }
    );
})};

// Jumping queued to another queue
function letJump2(element) {
    $(function() {
        element.queue("jump", function(next) {
            element.animate({width: "+=50", height: "+=20"}, {
                duration: "fast",
                queue: "jump"
            })
            .animate( {width: "-=50", height: "-=20"}, {
                duration: "fast",
                queue: "jump"
            });
            next();
        }).dequeue("jump");
    })
};


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* function update(progress) {} */

function draw() {
    state.innerHTML = animationOn;
    if (animationOn) {
        flashAnimation2(block);
    }
}

function loop(timestamp) {
    progress = timestamp - lastRender;
    /* update(progress); */
    draw();

    lastRender = timestamp;
    reqAnimF = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

button.addEventListener("click", changeStatus);
//jump.addEventListener("click", letJump1(block)); // button is dead for some reason

reqAnimF = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
.center {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
button {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}
#fadeInAndOut {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
#jump {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
    <h1 id="state"></h1>
    <button type="button" id="button">Flash on/off</button>
    <div id="fadeInAndOut"></div>
    <button type="button" id="jump" onclick="letJump1(block)">Jump</button>
</div>
```